# RandomAccessFile reading Cyrillic UTF-8 java

Tags: java, utf-8, randomaccessfile, cyrillic

mates!

I have trouble reading from file Cyrillic text using `RandomAccessFile`.

Here's a simple program, that writes information in specific file (Cyrillic words) using such format:

**`keyLength, valueLength, key, value`**

Then program tries to read this information, but my output is incorrect:

```
writing success
keyLength = 10, valueLength = 4
read: килло, гр
```

**UPD**
Expected output:

```
writing success
keyLength = 10, valueLength = 4
read: киллограмм, сала
```

What is the problem? (except problem that I have small brain)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "file.db";
        RandomAccessFile outputFile = null;

        try {
            outputFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String key = "киллограмм";
        String value = "сала";

        try {
            outputFile.writeInt(key.length());
            outputFile.writeInt(value.length());

            outputFile.write(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            outputFile.write(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("writing success");

        RandomAccessFile inputFile = null;

        try {
            inputFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int keyLength = 0, valueLength = 0;

        try {
            keyLength = inputFile.readInt();
            valueLength = inputFile.readInt();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("keyLength = " + keyLength + ", valueLength = " + valueLength);
        if (keyLength <= 0 || valueLength <= 0) {
            System.err.println("key or value length is negative");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        byte[] keyBytes = null, valueBytes = null;

        try {
            keyBytes = new byte[keyLength];
            valueBytes = new byte[valueLength];
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            inputFile.read(keyBytes);
            inputFile.read(valueBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("read: " + new String(keyBytes, "UTF-8") + ", " + new String(valueBytes, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, upd

Comment: If you were reading/writing sequentially, `java.io.Writer` and `Reader` would wrap an OutputStream/InputStream and handle the UTF-8 or other character encoding for you.  Are you sure these wouldn't be a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this

```
outputFile.writeInt(key.length());
```

`String#length()`

> Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number
>   of Unicode code units in the string.

In this case, it returns the value `10`, which is not the number of byte required to represent this String.

What you want is

```
key.getBytes("UTF-8").length
```

used as

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
outputFile.writeInt(keyBytes.length);
```

Same for the `value`.

Comment: @NinjaTurtle Also, you have a ton of `try-catch` blocks. Why don't you just wrap all your code in one block instead? You're always exiting the application anyway.